# How to make splitting two date ranges with nested functions and making a request to the API with Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, loops, nested

I am using a component that lists news by date range. The `API` I'm sending the request to returns only 90 days of data. My goal is to add the ability to select 1 year range to this component. Since the `API` can only return 90 days of data, I want to fetch data by dividing 1 year by 90 days. Also, the request should stop after the 90-day interval that first fetches `data`.

For Example:

```
startDate = 2021-12-27

endDate = 2022-12-27
```

90 days before the selected endDate (startDate = 2022-10-27). If there is data there should be loop break. If there is no data, it should send a request to the previous 90 days.

***My code:***

```
function requestToDataNews(startDate, endDate) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      http.get(`/test=&start_date=${startDate}&end_date=${endDate}`, { timeout: 40000 }
      )
        .then((response) => {
          if(response.data.response_code === 200){
            resolve(response.data);
          } else {
            reject(response.data);
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          reject(error);
        }).finally(() => {
          commit('loadingBar', false);
        });
    });
 }
 commit('loadingBar', true);
 let startDate = '2022-12-27';
 let endDate = '2021-12-27';
 
 const differentDays = tools.getDifferentDaysRange(endDate, startDate, 'days');
 const currentNewsData = [];
 
 if (differentDays > 90 && differentDays <= 365) {
   for (let i = 0; i < Math.ceil(differentDays / 90); i += 1){
     startDate = moment(endDate).subtract('months', 2).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
     const newsData = requestToDataNews(startDate, endDate);
     if (newsData.is_success) {
       currentNewsData.push(...newsData.data);
     }
   }
 }
}
```

***NOTE***: My code not working right.

Answer (score 0):

don't use string date for differeces. Use timestamp, and check dates..

```
function requestToDataNews(startDate, endDate) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    http.get(`/test=&start_date=${startDate}&end_date=${endDate}`, { timeout: 40000 })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.response_code === 200) {
          resolve(response.data);
        } else {
          reject(response.data);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        reject(error);
      }).finally(() => {
        commit('loadingBar', false);
      });
  });
}

const onStartDate = '2021-12-27';
const onEndDate = '2022-12-27';

// convert to timestamp
const startDateStamp = new Date(onStartDate).getTime();
const endDateStamp = new Date(onEndDate).getTime();

// difference days
const diffDaysStamp = Math.ceil((endDateStamp - startDateStamp) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

if (diffDaysStamp <= 90) {
  requestToDataNews(onStartDate, onEndDate);
} else {
  const diffDate = Math.ceil(diffDays / 90);
  const dateArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < diffDate; i++) {
    const startDate = new Date(onStartDate).getTime();
    const endDate = new Date(onEndDate).getTime();
    const diffDays = Math.ceil((endDate - startDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    if (diffDays <= 90) {
      dateArr.push({
        startDate: new Date(startDate).toISOString().slice(0, 10),
        endDate: new Date(endDate).toISOString().slice(0, 10),
      });
    } else {
      const newEndDate = new Date(startDate + 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
      dateArr.push({
        startDate: new Date(startDate).toISOString().slice(0, 10),
        endDate: new Date(newEndDate).toISOString().slice(0, 10),
      });
    }
  }
  dateArr.forEach((item) => {
    requestToDataNews(item.startDate, item.endDate);
  });
}
```

**It's example, and it's code may be not working.. I am not testing... I'm give you idea**